# Question about a proof on Spivak's Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

On the Addedum to the Chapter VI, vol. II, the first proposition states that to connections have the same geodesics if and only if their difference tensor is antisymmetric.

When proving that if the geodesics are the same the tensor is antisymmetric, he uses the following equality
$$
\nabla_{X_p}X = 0
$$

where the vector field $X$ is arbitrary. I don't understand why this shoud hold, since at a first moment this is only true when $X = \dot\gamma$ for a geodesic $\gamma$ (which is a geodesic for both connections).

It seems to me this is the same as stating that, at any point, every field has an integral curve that is a geodesic for a short interval around that point, which doesn't feel to me like it should be true.

Comment: This equality is indeed false in general. However, it is true if you replace $\nabla$ by the difference tensor.

Comment: If the difference tensor is $D(X,Y) = \nabla_XY - \widetilde{\nabla}_XY$ and the connections have the same geodesics then I agree that $D(\dot\gamma, \dot\gamma) = 0$ for any geodesic. What I cant understand is why this holds for arbitrary $X$.

Comment: It seems to me we're assuming that for any field $X$ and vector $X_p$ there is a geodesic $\gamma$ through $p$ satisfying $X \circ \gamma = \dot\gamma$, and I can't see why is this the case.

Comment: The difference tensor is a tensor and so only depends on the value of a vector field at a point. For every $X_p\in T_pM$ there exists a geodesic in the direction of $X_p$, and you can use it to evaluate your difference tensor.

Comment: So, no matter which vector fields I choose, I'll always have $D(X,Y)_p = D(\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y})_p$ as long $X_p = \tilde{X}_p$ and $ Y_p = \tilde{Y}_p$ ?

Comment: It makes sense when thinking about tensors, but it feels somewhat weird since $D$ is defined in terms of covariant derivatives and those depend on how the fields behave in a neighborhood of the point. It's like somehow taking their difference nullifies the effect the field's variation on a neighborhood have on the derivatives. Don't know if I'm making any sense right now.

Comment: What you are saying is correct and in fact a good exercise - the difference between two connections is a tensor. The best way I know of showing this is show that the difference is linear over the ring of smooth functions.